# How do I deploy an Strapi CLI app on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, strapi

I just started fresh Strapi project on my local machine and I keep it in bitbucket repo. So I have a need to deploy it Azure in Windows environment. I have successfully deploy Postgres on free tier basis and now a node web app which I have a problem with web.config rules and deployment

I tried googling around the custom web.config to redirect all request all `/public`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:
     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
            <add name="iisnode" path="{NodeStartFile}" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^{NodeStartFile}\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>

                <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{PATH_INFO}"/>
                </rule>

                <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="build/{R:1}"/>
                </rule>

                <rule name="Index" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.html"/>
                </rule>

                <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{NodeStartFile}"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Apparently this does not satisfy Strapi routing requirement. Instead I got 500 internal routing error. How to set it up properly where I can access my admin panel as well as the api? How to custom my `deploy.cmd` to do `strapi build`? What is the right approach to deploy on Azure?

I also logged an issue here for them to the documentation on it

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3576

Comment: Hi, Did you get to work your Strapi on Azure? Could you please share it? :)

Comment: Hi, eventually I switch to Ubuntu for easy deployment

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please answer to your post with Ubuntu example? How your pipelines looks and how did you configured your server. :)